# Splitting vertex at end of 4 lines, to fix tris

Tags: mesh

[image]

I am making a handle on a trunk. I beveled the inner corner on the handle. But it added 3 lines that end at a single vertex. Now i need to split the vertex ( one for each line) so i can fix the topology, and fix the tris. Not sure how to do this. Sent a pic so you get the idea. Whats going on and what im going for. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any magical way to do it, anyway I would do it with the knife tool:

[image]